# How can I reduce Hysteresis in the clickpad area?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics

I have a problem with my touchpad:
Every time I use the clickpad (left click or right click) the pointer moves a little bit (sometimes more than a little), so I end up clicking something I don't want to.
I found out that this can be solved by increasing the values of HorizHysteresis and VertHysteresis. But when I do that, the movement of the pointer with the thouchpad gets less fluent. 
So my question is: is there a way to increase the values of Hysteresis only in the clickpad area? So that the rest of the touchpad has a different Hysteresis value than the clickpad. 
That way the pointer wouldn't jump every time I click, but the movement in the touchpad would still be fluent.

Best regards,

Juan Manuel

Comment: Well, or we can make the hysteresis setup dynamically, only after click event. Then, It should be normal again. But, How?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
$ synclient HorizHysteresis=# VertHysteresis=#
```

You can check the default values by writing only synclient.
Though this method won't make the changes permanent, you can create a script and make it run when you log in.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read your question well the first time.
I had the same problem and what I did to solve it was to increase the values of FingerHigh and FingerLow. You could try with those.

Comment: Please edit your answer accordingly - comments are not meant for that.